# Why am I getting *worse* performance with a *larger* buffer in my BufferedReader?

Tags: java, performance, file-io, buffer, bufferedreader

I'm getting weird results I can't explain from a `BufferedReader` when I vary the size of the buffer.

I had strongly expected that performance would gradually increase as I increased the size of the buffer, with diminishing returns setting in fairly quickly, and that thereafter performance would be more or less flat. But it seems that, after only a very modest buffer size, **increasing the size of the buffer makes it slower**.

Here's a minimal example. All it does is run through a text file, and calculate the sum of the lengths of the lines.

```
public int traverseFile(int bufSize) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("words16"), bufSize*1024);
    String line;
    int total=0;
    while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null)
        total+=line.length();
    reader.close();
    return total;
}
```

I tried benchmarking this with various buffer sizes, and the results were rather odd. Up to about 256KB, performance increases; after that point, it gets worse. I wondered whether it was just the time taken to allocate the buffer, so I tried adding something in to make it always allocate the same total amount of memory (see second line below):

```
public int traverseFile(int bufSize) throws IOException {
    byte[] pad = new byte[(65536-bufSize)*1024];
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("words16"), bufSize*1024);
    String line;
    int total=0;
    while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null)
        total+=line.length();
    reader.close();
    return total;
}
```

This makes no odds. I am still getting the same results, on two different machines. Here are the full results:

```
Benchmark                                        Mode  Samples    Score   Error  Units
j.t.BufferSizeBenchmark.traverse_test1_4K        avgt      100  363.987 ± 1.901  ms/op
j.t.BufferSizeBenchmark.traverse_test2_16K       avgt      100  356.551 ± 0.330  ms/op
j.t.BufferSizeBenchmark.traverse_test3_64K       avgt      100  353.462 ± 0.557  ms/op
j.t.BufferSizeBenchmark.traverse_test4_256K      avgt      100  350.822 ± 0.562  ms/op
j.t.BufferSizeBenchmark.traverse_test5_1024K     avgt      100  356.949 ± 0.338  ms/op
j.t.BufferSizeBenchmark.traverse_test6_4096K     avgt      100  358.377 ± 0.388  ms/op
j.t.BufferSizeBenchmark.traverse_test7_16384K    avgt      100  367.890 ± 0.393  ms/op
j.t.BufferSizeBenchmark.traverse_test8_65536K    avgt      100  363.271 ± 0.228  ms/op
```

As you can see, the sweet spot is at about 256KB. The difference isn't huge, but it is certainly measurable.

All I can think is that this might be something to do with the memory cache. Is it because the RAM that's being written to is further away from the RAM that's being read? But if it's a cyclic buffer, I'm not even sure that's true: what's being written will be just behind what's being read.

The `words16` file is 80MB so I can't post it here, but it's Fedora's standard `/usr/share/dict/words` file, sixteen times over. I can find a way to post a link if necessary.

Here's the benchmarking code:

```
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OperationsPerInvocation(1)
@Warmup(iterations = 30, time = 100, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 100, time = 10000, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@State(Scope.Thread)
@Threads(1)
@Fork(1)
public class BufferSizeBenchmark {

    public int traverseFile(int bufSize) throws IOException {
        byte[] pad = new byte[(65536-bufSize)*1024];
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("words16"), bufSize*1024);
        String line;
        int total=0;
        while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null)
            total+=line.length();
        reader.close();
        return total;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public int traverse_test1_4K() throws IOException {
        return traverseFile(4);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public int traverse_test2_16K() throws IOException {
        return traverseFile(16);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public int traverse_test3_64K() throws IOException {
        return traverseFile(64);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public int traverse_test4_256K() throws IOException {
        return traverseFile(256);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public int traverse_test5_1024K() throws IOException {
        return traverseFile(1024);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public int traverse_test6_4096K() throws IOException {
        return traverseFile(4096);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public int traverse_test7_16384K() throws IOException {
        return traverseFile(16384);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public int traverse_test8_65536K() throws IOException {
        return traverseFile(65536);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException {
        Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
                .include(
                        ".*" + BufferSizeBenchmark.class.getSimpleName() + ".*")
                .forks(1).build();

        new Runner(opt).run();
    }

}
```

**Why am I getting worse performance when I increase the size of the buffer?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely an affect of the cache line size. Since cache uses LRU eviction policy using too large a buffer causes what you've written to the 'beggining' of the buffer to be evicted before you get a chance to read it.

Answer (score 1):

256k is a typical CPU cache size! What type of CPU you tested on?

So what happens is: If you read 256k chunks or smaller, the content that was written to the buffer is still in the CPU cache when the read accesses it. If you have chunks greater of 256k then the last 256k that were read are in the CPU cache, so when the read starts  from the beginning the content must be retrieved from main memory.

The second problem is with the buffer allocation. The trick with the padding buffer is clever, but does not really average out the allocation cost. The reason for this is, that the real cost of the allocation is not the reservation of the memory, but to clear it. Furthermore the OS may postpone to map in the real memory to the time it was first accessed. But you never access the padding buffer.